# How to reset ExtJS timefield when clicking on a button

Tags: extjs

I have two timefields:

```
items: [{
      margin: '0 20 0 0',
      align: 'middle',
      items: {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        name: 'startHourCombo',
        id: 'startTime',
        maxWidth: 100,
        columnWidth: 0.2,
        minValue: '12:00 AM',
        maxValue: '11:00 PM',
        increment: 60,
        anchor: '100%',
        value: '12:00 AM',
        disabled: false

      }
    },
    {
      xtype: 'timefield',
      name: 'endHourCombo',
      id: 'endTime',
      maxWidth: 100,
      minValue: '12:00 AM',
      maxValue: '11:00 PM',
      increment: 60,
      anchor: '100%',
      value: '12:00 AM',
      disabled: false

    }
```

and the button:

```
{
  xtype: 'button',
  text: 'reset',
  handler: function(btn) {
    btn.up('form').down('[name=startHourCombo]').reset();
    btn.up('form').down('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
    // i tried like this but getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null "
  }
}
```

By clicking on the button I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null

Please help me.

Comment: i am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null " can anyone help me

Comment: your button has `items` config? if possible, please post the whole code for the form

Answer (score 1):

I cant see any form in your code so `btn.up('form')` probably doesnt work.

You have to check your view structure and update your queries.

In general you can use [Ext.ComponentQuery.query()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html#method-query), like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
```

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27k9).

*Also, I think you have to read about [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html).*